# Edit, update record with DAO.Recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, dao

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`. In `Table1` there is Column called `FileID` and `Table2` there is column  called `FileID`.  Now `FileID` is not unique, so there are certain rows where `FileID` is repeated in both tables. 
I have a Form in Access, where there is field called `GetDate` from `Table1`.
I need something in vba that if you make changes to the `GetDate` part on the form (which is from `Table1` table) then it should update column `Date` with the current date and Time which is in `Table2`

I did it the following way. But its updating only the first record of `Date` From `Table2` with current time and not the second one with `FileID = 1`. 
there are two records for `FileID = 1`, in `table2` so it should update 2 records with current date and not one.
here is my code for it.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub GetDate_AfterUpdate()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
' Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset


Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT  [GetDate], [DATE] FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID2 where Table1.FileID = Table1.FileID", dbOpenDynaset)
'Begin row processing
Do While Not rst.EOF
rst.Edit
rst![Date] = Now
rst.Update
rst.MoveNext
Exit Do

Loop



rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing


End Sub
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: The code looks fine, so the error must be in the query that you use to  set the recordset. Have you tried running that as a query on its own and ensuring that it returns both records? If not, edit it until it does!

Comment: The query returns the whole set records from both tables. Which I don't need. So my other question is, can I make a query that can read the "FileID" field from a form. E.g. I am trying to edit "GetDate" field on the form and the "FileID" for that current record is, lets say 2.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that's a job for Google and a little while playing about with the query. You do however, have a strange WHERE condition in there which might be a starting point: where Table1.FileID = Table1.FileID will always be true, so all the records will be returned. If that's what you want, then it's redundant and should be taken out. If it's not what you want (as I suspect), then I would guess that's where your error is.

Comment: Your query `SELECT  [GetDate], [DATE] FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID2 where Table1.FileID = Table1.FileID` need only be `SELECT  [GetDate], [DATE] FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID2`; the `WHERE` clause expression will always be true, and is only wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have an exit do after your movenext, that shouldn't be there if you want to loop through all the records.

The rst.eof will exit the loop when it gets to the end of the file.

The way you have it written it will exit after the first record.

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
 rst.Edit
 rst![Date] = Now
 rst.Update
 rst.MoveNext
 Exit Do 'This will exit loop after first record
Loop
```

Do this instead

```
Do 
 rst.Edit
 rst![Date] = Now
 rst.Update
 rst.MoveNext
Loop Until rst.EOF
```

Comment: I advise you to use `Do Until rst.EOF` [...] `Loop` instead, because if the record is empty it will raise an error when first executing the loop.